# error after typing npm install -g @angular/cli

Tags: angular7

C:\Users\91732>npm install - g @angular/cli
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to http://infynexus/nexus/repository/npm-all/- failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND infynexus
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a proxy problem:

First try to delete your npm proxy configuration:

```
npm config delete proxy
```

Try to run the npm install again.

If it still doesn't work you will have to set manually the proxy configurations (maybe you are in a company)

```
npm config set proxy "http://username:password@proxy.company.com:port"
npm config set https-proxy "http://username:password@proxy.company.com:port"
```

If any of above changes works, try to change your repository url:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Run npm install (even you have any error) and set new repo:

```
npm install

npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

then try again

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```